# java.sql.Date erroneous formatting

Tags: java, date

I have this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String parsed = "15/07/2015";
    java.util.Date date = format.parse(parsed);
    java.sql.Date sql = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
    System.out.println(sql);
}
```

where I am trying to get the date format as `15/07/2015` to insert into the DB. Whereas, everytime it provides me an output as **`2015-07-15`**. I do not understand why is it so.

- Is it because the default date date formatting for `java.sql.Date` is `yyyy-MM-dd`.?
- Or, do I need to set a different date format after parsing into `java.sql.Date`?

Any suggestions or guidance would help. Thanks

Comment: You're not storing a date string in your DB, you're storing a date.

Comment: Yes you are right. Does it mean that I will be unable to view the date from my DB as dd-MM-yyyy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `java.sql.Date` corresponds to `SQL DATE` which means and it will store in the format of `year-month-date`.
You can not format a date.
If you want it to be in the format `2015-07-15` then you will have to convert date to string using date formatter.

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String date1 = format1.format(date);   //date is your date from db
```

here `date1` will be in the required format

**Step 1)** Store the date in database as date only

```
  java.util.Date date = format.parse(parsed);
  // code to store date to db
```

**Step2 )** While displaying data to `JTable`

Get date from database

```
date = getdatefromdatabase(); // method like this
```

then use the date formatter

```
   SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
   String date1 = format1.format(date);   //date is your date from db
```

Send this `date1` to `jtable`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But as I am trying to filter a `JTable` ultimately based on date ranges. Will it work if I provide a Date format like this?

Comment: yes you can do it . you should store it in database format and when you display it you need to format it.you dont need to store it in that format. And if you want to store in that format then change datatype to string and store by formatting the date

Comment: Could you help me with setting the date format to `dd-MM-yyyy` before sending it to a `JTable`. ?

Comment: i have editted the code.can help you more if you will show me the code where you get the data to display to jtable

Comment: Actually I am using `rs2xml` and I found that I need to modify the code, if I want to do such a thing. But, nevertheless it gives me the correct date filtering in whatever format(currently using dd-MM-yyyy) I provide it to a `JTable` through a `datepicker`. So, as a conclusion : Java is so Holy that it understands everything :). Solved my problem.

Comment: This Answer is incorrect. [A] No database I've heard of stores a date value as year-month-day. They store in their own internal format. [B] Bad advice to be use a String for database insertion when we have a `java.sql.Date` object. The *entire purpose* of java.sql.* classes is to pass data between a database and your Java app. See the [correct Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31436773/642706).

Answer (score 3):

A `java.sql.Date`, like a `java.util.Date`, stores a date value that is unformatted.  When you pass it to `System.out.println`, `toString()` is called on it.  The [`toString()` method on `java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--) prints the date in "yyyy-mm-dd" format.

You don't need to set any date format.  If you need a specific format in Java, you can use your `SimpleDateFormat` object to format it into a `String`; a `java.sql.Date` is a `java.util.Date`.  But you can pass the `java.sql.Date` directly to the database; that is for what it was designed.  Most likely your database has some kind of conversion function(s) for formatting and parsing date values like Java does.

Comment: So, here is what I am actually trying : In a Jtable I need to filter the dates, say between Date1 and Date2 and give the search results based on that. So, here will it work if I provide Date in any format?

Comment: I would parse whatever string you're getting as a date in Java, pass it as a `java.sql.Date` to the database, receive the `java.sql.Date`s back from the DB, and then format them when displaying them to the user.

Comment: @mustangDC You are confusing date-time values with strings. That is like confusing the characters "1" and "3" for the number 13. Databases do not store date-time values as strings, they have [date-time data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_types). Java does not handle date-time values as strings; Java offers at least 3 date-time frameworks with classes to represent date-time values: [1] java.util.Date/.Calendar, [2] java.time built into Java 8 and later, [3] the 3rd-party Joda-Time library. The java.sql.* classes shuttle data between databases and Java apps w/o string conversions.